# Using Bootstrap classes with ReactJS and Webpack

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack

I dont know how to include Bootstrap to my React application. Ive created template of this app by Yeoman, generator-react-webpack V2.0 and it created some depndencies automatically. but I would like to use bootstrap classes too and I tried to install bootstrap-loader via npm but it doesnt work out (boostrap classes aren't applied). Could someone help me and explain how to setup a React project with webpack and bootstrap, cause I can not deal with it.
I tried this:

```
npm install bootstrap-loader
npm install bootstrap@v4.0.0-alpha.2
```

This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```js
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const args = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));

// List of allowed environments
const allowedEnvs = ['dev', 'dist', 'test'];

// Set the correct environment
var env;
if(args._.length > 0 && args._.indexOf('start') !== -1) {
  env = 'test';
} else if (args.env) {
  env = args.env;
} else {
  env = 'dev';
}
process.env.REACT_WEBPACK_ENV = env;

// Get available configurations
const configs = {
  base: require(path.join(__dirname, 'cfg/base')),
  dev: require(path.join(__dirname, 'cfg/dev')),
  dist: require(path.join(__dirname, 'cfg/dist')),
  test: require(path.join(__dirname, 'cfg/test'))
};

/**
 * Build the webpack configuration
 * @param  {String} wantedEnv The wanted environment
 * @return {Object} Webpack config
 */
function buildConfig(wantedEnv) {
  let isValid = wantedEnv && wantedEnv.length > 0 && allowedEnvs.indexOf(wantedEnv) !== -1;
  let validEnv = isValid ? wantedEnv : 'dev';
  return configs[validEnv];
}

module.exports = buildConfig(env);
```

It was automatically generated by yeoman generator.

and these are my config files.
base.js:

```js
'use strict';
let path = require('path');
let defaultSettings = require('./defaults');

// Additional npm or bower modules to include in builds
// Add all foreign plugins you may need into this array
// @example:
// let npmBase = path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules');
// let additionalPaths = [ path.join(npmBase, 'react-bootstrap') ];
let additionalPaths = [];

module.exports = {
  additionalPaths: additionalPaths,
  port: defaultSettings.port,
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'eval',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/../dist/assets'),
    filename: 'app.js',
    publicPath: defaultSettings.publicPath
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './src/',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    port: defaultSettings.port,
    publicPath: defaultSettings.publicPath,
    noInfo: false
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      actions: `${defaultSettings.srcPath}/actions/`,
      components: `${defaultSettings.srcPath}/components/`,
      sources: `${defaultSettings.srcPath}/sources/`,
      stores: `${defaultSettings.srcPath}/stores/`,
      styles: `${defaultSettings.srcPath}/styles/`,
      config: `${defaultSettings.srcPath}/config/` + process.env.REACT_WEBPACK_ENV
    }
  },
  module: {}
};
```

default.js:

```js
'use strict';
const path = require('path');
const srcPath = path.join(__dirname, '/../src');
const dfltPort = 8000;
function getDefaultModules() {
  return {
    preLoaders: [{
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: srcPath,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      }],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded&indentedSyntax'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded'
      },
      {
        test: /\.less/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!less-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!stylus-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
      },

      { test: /bootstrap\/js\//, 
        loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery'
      },

      { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,   
        loader: "url?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff" 
      },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,    
        loader: "url?limit=10000&minetype=application/octet-stream" 
      },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,    
        loader: "file" 
      },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,    
        loader: "url?limit=10000&minetype=image/svg+xml" 
      }
    ]
  };
}
module.exports = {
  srcPath: srcPath,
  publicPath: '/assets/',
  port: dfltPort,
  getDefaultModules: getDefaultModules,
  postcss: function () {
    return [];
  }
};
```

dev.js:

```js
'use strict';

let path = require('path');
let webpack = require('webpack');
let baseConfig = require('./base');
let defaultSettings = require('./defaults');

// Add needed plugins here
let BowerWebpackPlugin = require('bower-webpack-plugin');

let config = Object.assign({}, baseConfig, {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:' + defaultSettings.port,
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    'bootstrap-loader',
    './src/index.jsx'
  ],
  cache: true,
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new BowerWebpackPlugin({
      searchResolveModulesDirectories: false
    })
  ],
  module: defaultSettings.getDefaultModules()
});

// Add needed loaders to the defaults here
config.module.loaders.push({
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  loader: 'react-hot!babel-loader',
  include: [].concat(
    config.additionalPaths,
    [ path.join(__dirname, '/../src') ]
  )
});

module.exports = config;
```

dist.js:

```js
'use strict';

let path = require('path');
let webpack = require('webpack');
let baseConfig = require('./base');
let defaultSettings = require('./defaults');

// Add needed plugins here
let BowerWebpackPlugin = require('bower-webpack-plugin');

let config = Object.assign({}, baseConfig, {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:' + defaultSettings.port,
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    'bootstrap-loader',
    './src/index.jsx'
  ],
  cache: true,
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new BowerWebpackPlugin({
      searchResolveModulesDirectories: false
    })
  ],
  module: defaultSettings.getDefaultModules()
});

// Add needed loaders to the defaults here
config.module.loaders.push({
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  loader: 'react-hot!babel-loader',
  include: [].concat(
    config.additionalPaths,
    [ path.join(__dirname, '/../src') ]
  )
});

module.exports = config;
```

test.js:

```js
'use strict';

let path = require('path');
let srcPath = path.join(__dirname, '/../src/');

let baseConfig = require('./base');

// Add needed plugins here
let BowerWebpackPlugin = require('bower-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'isparta-instrumenter-loader',
        include: [
          path.join(__dirname, '/../src')
        ]
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|css|sass|scss|less|styl)$/,
        loader: 'null-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [].concat(
          baseConfig.additionalPaths,
          [
            path.join(__dirname, '/../src'),
            path.join(__dirname, '/../test')
          ]
        )
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '', '.js', '.jsx' ],
    alias: {
      actions: srcPath + 'actions/',
      helpers: path.join(__dirname, '/../test/helpers'),
      components: srcPath + 'components/',
      sources: srcPath + 'sources/',
      stores: srcPath + 'stores/',
      styles: srcPath + 'styles/',
      config: srcPath + 'config/' + process.env.REACT_WEBPACK_ENV
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new BowerWebpackPlugin({
      searchResolveModulesDirectories: false
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: What is your `webpack.config.js` file

Answer (score 0):

This library can help you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-webpack

You just need to include `require("bootstrap-webpack!./bootstrap.config.js");` to every webpack entry file.

Comment: then is shows me error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: adding of     
  plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
        })
    ]

to webpack config will solve the problem. JQuery has to installed using npm too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, its very simple to use bootstrap with react js. Just include the bootstrap files in your application (for eg. by CDN). Then in any div, you can use 
 
    `className = '<bootstrap_class_name>'`

```
<div className = ' img img-responsive '>
    <ReactComponent />
</div>
```